# Scrollbar visible even when is not necessary -

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have an error using overflow:auto.

The error: http://cl.ly/image/0K1W3t151T0S

The code I used http://codepen.io/sebazelonka/pen/pDGin

Even when the height of the content has the same height than container, the scrollbar is visible. I tried different options, but the error persist.

I tried it in different browsers, including FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera, and always have the same error.

HTML

```
<div class="image-viewport portrait" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
      <div class="image-wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
           <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersview.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/landscape_7.jpg">
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #999;
}

.image-viewport {
  overflow: auto;
}

.image-wrapper {
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

.image-viewport.portrait img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 different solutions:

- Add `vertical-align:top` to the `img` element. (default is `vertical-align:baseline`)
- Change the `img` to a `block` level element.

[**Updated Codepen example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/viImK) using `vertical-align:top`

```
.image-viewport.portrait img {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**Updated Codepen example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rHlIp) using `display:block`

**Note:** For horizontal centering, use `margin:0 auto`, as `text-align:center` will no longer work, as the element is not an `inline` element anymore.

```
.image-viewport.portrait img {
    height: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Also, don't be confused with the scrollbar added on the body if the window is too small. The scrollbar on the `img` wrapper has been removed.

Comment: So why does a height of 100% need to be vertically aligned to the top? Seems like 100% = 100% and the elements should just fit inside each other without overflow.

Comment: @edhedges It has nothing to do with the heights. It's just the fact that the default alignment is baseline. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/4W2nq/)

Comment: That example just confuses me. Why are the divs that wrap the images different heights? The vertical align one fill the whole divs height and the baseline one doesn't. I don't understand why though.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `.image-viewport` class to this:

```
.image-viewport {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I need to keep it Auto, because that image can be zoomed, and I need to have scroll to navigate it.

Comment: You should specify that in your question. I'm not sure of a way for the image to fill the whole element without it triggering the scrollbar. You are resizing an image into a 400px tall element and the image is 1200px tall. If you give the height of 99% the scrollbar goes away, but then there is a small gap of the gray background showing at the bottom. I'm unsure of how to solve your problem, but am curious as to how it can be solved.

Comment: @edhedges `overflow:none` isn't a valid property. You may be thinking of `overflow:hidden`. Anyways, check out my answer if you are curious to know how to solve it.

Comment: @JoshC thanks I've edited my answer to reflect the correct syntax.